# Call method based on the type of the generic list element

Tags: java, generics

I have a `List` defined with generics. All elements in this list define the interface `TransferableData`. Depending on the object that eventually populates the list, i want to call a method to do something with the data.

So I want to archive something like this:

```
private <T extends TransferableData> String doSomething(List<T> data, Class<T> dataType){
    if(returnType.equals(A.class)){
       for(T singleElement : data){
          ((A)singleElement).methodInsideA();
       }
    }else if(returnType.equals(B.class)){
       for(T singleElement : data){
          ((B)singleElement).methodInsideB();
       }
   }
}
```

I realize that this is NOT the way to do this. I just cannot find a proper way without all the if-else and the unchecked casting.

Comment: What you need is a different design approach - looks a bit in the direction of Strategy Pattern.

Comment: Why don't you just declare that method in `TransferableData`, invoke it non-conditionally inside your method on each list element, and implement it as you wish in your concrete classes?

Comment: Did you mean to write `dataType` where you wrote `returnType`?

Comment: Also, I'm curious how you intend to call this method. If the caller knows the actual element type statically, and can do something like `doSomething(data, A.class)`, why not just use `data.forEach(A::methodInsideA)` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the assumption that your classes are implementing `TransferableData` interface, you can add a method `invokeMethod()` which has void as return type. For below solution to work, you should have same method signature in all the classes.

```
public interface TransferableData {
    void invokeMethod();
}


public class A implements TransferableData {

   @Override
   public void invokeMethod() {
        //Your business logic A
   }
}

public class B implements TransferableData {

    @Override
    public void invokeMethod() {
        //Your business logic for B
    }
}
```

Iterate over your list of objects as (No need to pass dataType to this method):

```
private <T extends TransferableData> String doSomething(List<T> data) {

  for(T object: data){
      object.invokeMethod();
  }
  //return the string according to your business logic.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment from Mena you can try something like this,

```
public interface TransferableData {

    void genericInvoker();
}


public class A implements TransferableData {

    @Override
    public void genericInvoker() {
        methodInsideA();
    }

    void methodInsideA(){
        // Do specific thing to A
    }
}

public class B implements TransferableData {

    @Override
    public void genericInvoker() {
        methodInsideB();
    }

    void methodInsideB(){
        // Do specific thing to B
    }
}
```

Then you can invoke the methods as follows:

```
private <T extends TransferableData> String doSomething(List<T> data, Class<T> dataType){

  for(T singleElement : data){
      singleElement.genericInvoker();
  }

  //Don't forget to return a String from this method
}
```